# Converting a parent child relationship into Json in python

Tags: python, json, parent

I have a list of list like the below.  The first column is the parent, second is the child, and the third are node attributes.  I need to convert the below to a JSON format like the following.

```
0 0 "flair" 1000
0 1 "analytics" 1000

1 2 "cluster" 1000
2 3 "AgglomerativeCluster" 1000
2 4 "CommunityStructure" 1000

1 5 "Graph" 1000
5 6 "BetweennessCentrality" 1000
5 7 "LinkDistance"
```

---

```
pc = []
pc.append([0, 0 ,"flair", 1000])
pc.append([0,1, "analytics", 1000])
pc.append([1, 2, "cluster", 1000])
pc.append([2 ,3, "AgglomerativeCluster", 1000])
pc.append([2 ,4, "CommunityStructure" ,1000])
pc.append([1 ,5, "Graph", 1000])
pc.append([5, 6, "BetweennessCentrality", 1000])
pc.append([5, 7, "LinkDistance",1000])

{
 "name": "flare",
 "children": [
  {
   "name": "analytics",
   "children": [
    {
     "name": "cluster",
     "children": [
      {"name": "AgglomerativeCluster", "size": 3938},
      {"name": "CommunityStructure", "size": 3812},
     ]
    },
    {
     "name": "graph",
     "children": [
      {"name": "BetweennessCentrality", "size": 3534},
      {"name": "LinkDistance", "size": 5731}
     ]
    }
   ]
  }
 ]
}
```

Comment: I converted the list of lists to this format... child_parent={0: {'name': 'flair', 'parent': 0, 'size': 1000}, 1: {'name': 'analytics', 'parent': 0, 'size': 1000}, 2: {'name': 'cluster', 'parent': 1, 'size': 1000}, 3: {'name': 'AgglomerativeCluster', 'parent': 2, 'size': 1000}, 4: {'name': 'CommunityStructure', 'parent': 2, 'size': 1000}, 5: {'name': 'Graph', 'parent': 1, 'size': 1000}, 6: {'name': 'BetweennessCentrality', 'parent': 5, 'size': 1000}, 7: {'name': 'LinkDistance', 'parent': 5, 'size': 1000}}

Answer (score 3):

A little change to your input, for a root node "flair", I use '-1' as its parent id instead of '0'.

```
import json
pc = []
pc.append([-1, 0 ,"flair", 1000])
pc.append([0,1, "analytics", 1000])
pc.append([1, 2, "cluster", 1000])
pc.append([2 ,3, "AgglomerativeCluster", 1000])
pc.append([2 ,4, "CommunityStructure" ,1000])
pc.append([1 ,5, "Graph", 1000])
pc.append([5, 6, "BetweennessCentrality", 1000])
pc.append([5, 7, "LinkDistance",1000])

def listToDict(input):
    root = {}
    lookup = {}
    for parent_id, id, name, attr in input:
        if parent_id == -1: 
            root['name'] = name;
            lookup[id] = root
        else:
            node = {'name': name}
            lookup[parent_id].setdefault('children', []).append(node)
            lookup[id] = node
    return root

result = listToDict(pc)
print result
print json.dumps(result)
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure where those 'size' attributes are coming from, they don't appear in the 'pc' list, but assuming they're taken from the 4th item in each list and they should all be 1000 in the output tree, this should work

```
def make_tree(pc_list):
    results = {}
    for record in pc_list:
        parent_id = record[0]
        id = record[1]

        if id in results:
            node = results[id]
        else:
            node = results[id] = {}

        node['name'] = record[2]
        node['size'] = record[3]
        if parent_id != id:
            if parent_id in results:
                parent = results[parent_id]
            else:
                parent = results[parent_id] = {}
            if 'children' in parent:                
                parent['children'].append(node)
            else:
                parent['children'] = [node]        

    # assuming we wanted node id #0 as the top of the tree          
    return results[0]
```

pretty printing the output of make_tree(pc) I get

```
{'children': [{'children': [{'children': [{'name': 'AgglomerativeCluster',
                                           'size': 1000},
                                          {'name': 'CommunityStructure',
                                           'size': 1000}],
                             'name': 'cluster',
                             'size': 1000},
                            {'children': [{'name': 'BetweennessCentrality',
                                           'size': 1000},
                                          {'name': 'LinkDistance',
                                           'size': 1000}],
                             'name': 'Graph',
                             'size': 1000}],
               'name': 'analytics',
               'size': 1000}],
 'name': 'flair',
 'size': 1000}
```

which although the ordering of the key display is different, is almost like your sample output (except for the size values)